# Borland C++ v5.5 installation procedure

Tags: c++, c++builder-5

I have downloaded the latest version available of Borland C++ 5.5 compiler. I have installed the exe file but the program doesn't run.

I have got this in READ ME file of the installation package but I cant make out anything..

> Installing and running the Command Line Tools
>
> ---
>
> 1. Run freecommandlinetools.exe; choose the     drive and folder into
>      which you want to    install the free
>      C++Builder 5 command line     tool
>      development system.
> 2. From the bin directory of your installation:    a. Add
>      "c:\Borland\Bcc55" 
>        to the existing path    b. Create a bcc32.cfg file which will set
>
>    the compiler options for the Include 
>        and Lib paths (-I and -L switches to 
>        compiler) by adding these lines:
>        -I"c:\Borland\Bcc55\include"
>        -L"c:\Borland\Bcc55\lib"    c. Create an ilink32.cfg file which will
>      set 
>        the linker option for the Lib path by 
>        adding this line:
>        -L"c:\Borland\Bcc55\lib"

Please help me to understand this.

Comment: Exactly what does happen if you try to run it? And are you aware that this is a compiler without a grafical user interface?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Borland 5.5 is an extremely old compiler.

It doesn't even implement std::string properly.

Use a more modern compiler, like g++ or Visual C++ (they're both free).

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use Borland C++ XE3, XE2, or 6.0 at least.
There were so many bugs in Borland 5.5 which will confuse you, or make trouble to your project.